# Error using conv2 N-D arrays are not supported

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I wrote this code to Compute gradient vector at each pixel by convolving the image with horizontal and vertical derivative filters, then computed the gradient magnitude at each pixel , but I get the following error in `conv2`:

> Error using conv2 N-D arrays are not supported.
>   Error in X (line 7) Gx=conv2(A,Sx)

```
  A=imread('peppers.png');
figure,imshow(A); title('Sobel Gradient Before');
V= double (A);

Sx = [1,0,-1;2,0,-2;1,0,-1];
        Gx=Conv2(A,Sx);
        figure
        imshow(Gx); title('x-direction');

Sy = [1,2,1;0,0,0;-1,-2,-1];
        Gy=Conv2(A,Sy);
        figure
        imshow(Gy); title('y-direction');

        G=sqrt(Gx.^2+Gy.^2);
        figure,imshow(G); title('Sobel Gradient After');
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Error using conv2
N-D arrays are not supported.

Error in X (line 7)
        Gx=conv2(A,Sx);

Comment: Please don't use bold formatting. It looks like you're shouting.

Comment: I try it but I have same Error

Answer (score 4):

For color images, `imread` returns a 3D array where the 3rd dimension has 3 elements for R, G, B. You need to convert the image to grey-value first. Or do the convolution on the color image using `convn`.

To convert the image to grayscale, use the [`rgb2gray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2gray.html) function.